# case statement to prevent opening of certain files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Dir of files; most are unique, but some are variations of others e.g. `Hires Month 1`, `Hires Month 2` etc.... I want to skip over these when opening files, so I made a Case statement with a `like` operator, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    Dim BasePath As String: BasePath = "\\All Data\" & strFolderName & "\"
Dim filename As String: filename = Dir(BasePath & "\*.xlsx")
Dim wb As Workbook
    i = 0
    Do While filename <> ""
        Select Case True
            Case filename Like "Store*"
            Case filename Like "Hires Month*"
            Case filename Like "Current - Store*"
            Case filename Like "Terms Month*"
            Case Else
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(BasePath & "\" & filename)
            i = i + 1
                With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Cells(1, 1)
                End With
            wb.Close
            filename = Dir
        End Select
    Loop
```

What could be causing the logic not to apply when supposedly triggered?

Comment: Does the like only apply to the first? or are these getting skipped too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it round, thus

```
Select Case True
       Case filename Like "Store*", filename Like "Hires Month*", filename Like "Current - Store*", filename Like "Terms Month*"
```

Comment: So when I do this, it triggers the first instance of `Store *.xlsx`, and skips to `Loop`, but it never opens another file....its stuck on the first Case statement file

Comment: @NidenK Try moving `filename = Dir` outside the Select Case.